# Snakemake: How to prevent ambiguous rules from being executed both?

Tags: python, snakemake

I am using snakemake in a machine-learning context. I have two rules (`process_x_only`, and `process_x_and_y`) that have `processed_x.txt` as target output, and are thus ambiguous. See following code:

```
rule process_x_only:
    input:
        'x.txt',
    output:
        'processed_x.txt'

rule process_x_and_y:
    input:
        'x.txt',
        'y.txt'
    output:
        'processed_x.txt',
        'processed_y.txt'

ruleorder: process_x_only > process_x_and_y

rule refit_model:
    input:
        'processed_x.txt',
        'processed_y.txt'
    output:
        'predictions_refit.txt'

rule predict_model:
    input:
        'processed_x.txt'
    output:
        'predictions.txt'
```

Following snakemake's [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html), I use a `ruleorder` statement to specify that preferably only x should be processed ( I.e. only when y **needs** to be processed `process_x_and_y` should be run, otherwise it is sufficient to just process x and `process_x_only` can be run.). This resolves the ambiguity problem, but introduces another problem. When I execute:

```
snakemake predictions_refit.txt
```

snakemake will first execute `process_x_only`, and then `process_x_and_y`, whereas in this case I only want `process_x_and_y` to be executed. How do I make snakemake build a DAG where only `process_x_and_y` is executed?

To clarify: This is a big simplification of my actual problem. I am aware that changing the restrictions of my problem statement will solve the problem, but I am interested in how to solve that snakemake is executing both rules in the ruleorder.

To add: While executing rule `refit model` the following warning is displayed:

```
Warning: the following output files of rule process_x_only were not 
present when the DAG was created:

{'processed_x.txt'}
```

Comment: I think you should use ruleorder this way then:
`ruleorder: process_x_and_y > process_x_only`
(also there was a typo)

Comment: @rioualen: this would solve the problem, but (as I mentioned) `process_x_only` is the preferred rule. I.e. only when y **needs** to be processed `process_x_and_y` should be run, otherwise it is sufficient to just process x and `process_x_only` can be run.  I added a bit more context in the question so this is clear, and I fixed the typo, thanks :)

Comment: So when `process_x_only` is to be used, you would already dispose of the `processed_y.txt` file right? If not, `process_x_and_y` would have to be executed anyway

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you propose to just always run `process_x_and_y` and then dispose of `processed_y.txt`. This would indeed be an easy solution, but it is incomplete. I am interested in a solution where `process_x_and_y` is only executed when strictly necessary. For example, take into account that processing both x and y is more computationally expensive than just processing x. Another easy solution would be to have a `process_y` rule instead of a `process_x_and_y` rule, but also that doesn't work in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. I didn't know snakemake would not be able to solve this on it's own. A hack would be to tell snakemake which rule produces the files for `refit_model`

```
rule refit_model:
    input:
        rules.process_x_and_y.output
    output:
        'predictions_refit.txt'
```

However, you can still get in trouble in a more complicated workflow, or if you try to run `snakemake refit_model predict_model`. Does the hack solve the problem for you?

For a real solution i think snakemake would have to prune the DAG after creating it. I suggest you open a new issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using rule dependencies. This indeed will solve the problem I stated here. Unfortunately my workflow is more complex than this simple example.

Comment: Pruning the DAG after creating it would indeed be the best solution. I will open a new issue for it.

Comment: I opened up a new issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/897/prune-dag-after-creation-to-prevent-double)